# Regex without middle expression repetition (axb|cxd)

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am just continuously hitting a wall with this one, I cannot solve it.  I am trying to get a regex that executes as:

```
(axb|cxd)
```

except without repeating x in the expression (as it is really long encoding-matching expression).  This is tested against a large string where I only need to match x for string replacement, so zero-width lookahead/behind is an option.  Any ideas?

a,b,c, and d are reasonably small, so they can repeat if it makes the expression easier to form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language? The answer could vary depending on your regex variant.

Comment: Javascript.  If it ports to .NET as well, that would be helpful as they will be playing together, but if I have a Javascript-only expression for now, I will be happy.

Comment: @SimpleCoder that will match axd and cxb.  Excluding those two cases is the trick I am not seeing. (Sorry, comment system is only allowing me to reply here)

Comment: I know, that's why I deleted my answer

Comment: I'm guessing it would be difficult to  use the `(a|c)x(b|d)` pattern and then do further checking to make sure you haven't actually matched `axd` or `cxb`?

Comment: @jswolf19 that's the most likely path I see so far, do (a|c)(x)(b|d) and check the results of \1 and \3 in script.  Just looking at the expression, it seemed so elementary in structure that I figured it may have been a solved (albeit intricate) thing I was overlooking.  I imagine this structure comes up a lot.

Comment: This would be pretty easy in many regex flavors, but JavaScript lacks the necessary features.  A pure regex solution *might* be possible, but it would be one very ugly regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to repeat x in the regular expression, then you'll have to apply some manual search logic.  You can search for x with the regular expression and then, based on where it was found, look for a before it and b after it or c before it and d after it.  But, that would likely be more work than just repeating it in the regular expression as in Gabe's answer.

For example, you could do this:

```
var re = /(a|c)x(b|d)/;
var matches = str.match(re);
if (matches) {
    // exclude axd or cxb
    if ((matches[1] + matches[2]).match(/ab|cd/)) {
        // found axb or cxd
    }
}
```

But, honestly, it seems like it would just be easier to include x twice and let the regex engine do the dirty work for you:

```
if (str.match(axb|cxd)) {
    // found match
}
```

Or, if it's too cumbersome to put x in the string twice, then build the regex yourself using javascript string math:

```
var x = "long complicated regex";
var re = new RegExp("a" + x + "b|c" + x + "d");
if (str.match(re)) {
    // found match
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way around it. You have to do something like this:

```
var x = "long, complicated regular expression";
var re = new RegExp("a" + x + "b|c" + x + "d");
```